# Is it bad to ask not to be recorded in a (group) interview?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism

I went to a group interview. (Not the same one as my other question, just coincidentally another one). On the whole I felt things went well. It was for a marketing position. At one point we were asked to act out a scene where we approached someone and tried to sell them something. This was done in a group of 3. The interviewers said "if you don't mind we're going to record this". I said I did mind.

I've had other interviews recorded and I did not mind at all. However I was told right away I was being recorded and it was through Skype. The main reason I said no in this situation was because I wanted to focus as much energy as possible on the task at hand and I think most people feel at least a little distracted knowing they are being recorded. Presumably they are using the recording for some work purpose, so in a sense I felt like it was doing free work.

These are pretty small reasons, so should I have just been ok with it? Would it negatively affect the chance of getting hired? Does it make a difference if the recording is audio only, photographs or video? Out of curiosity, would it ever be ok for the interviewee to ask to record the interview, or to ask for a copy of the recording the interviewer made?

Comment: I would not agree to be recorded in any interview situation, and I wouldn't care if it negatively impacts on my chances - it will already have impacted the recruiters chances of hiring me.

Comment: @HorusKol please, don't answer in comments

Comment: @DsrkCygnus it's not really an answer to the questions - it's an opinion/preference.

Comment: Could you add location? Under GDPR the need to record (in any way) would need to be expressed BEFORE the interview started.

Comment: @HorusKol comments are for improving the question, not expressing your preferences and opinions.

Answer (score 9):

> Would it negatively affect the chance of getting hired?

Yes.

Any time an interviewer asks you to do something and you decline, it will hurt your changes of getting hired - if only a little.

You get to decide how important it is for you not to be recorded.

Answer (score 1):

> At one point we were asked to act out a scene where we approached someone and tried to sell them something. [...] Presumably they are using the recording for some work purpose, so in a sense I felt like it was doing free work.

What work purpose would it be? Are they a sales people training company?

> Would it negatively affect the chance of getting hired?

Usually, recordings are used to show decision-makers not already in the room. At the very least, you should have asked what the purpose of the recording was.

If that was the case, I would have said "Yes".

Comment: That's a good point. It once happened they only wanted to take pictures so I don't think it was so someone else could make a decision. I said no because it would probably be used to promote the company and I didn't feel like doing free work.